# Windows media encoder Library cannnot be created

Tags: c#, encoder, windows-media-encoder

I have an application that records video from webcam. It works on my 64-bit window, but this doesn't work in 32-bit version.

Actually I just try to initiate an WME Object from this below statement. But it seems not work.
When I try to do debugging, it cannot detect any exceptions and it just terminate the debugging process.

```
WMEncoder Encoder = new WMEncoder();
```

So I am confuse now, is the problem caused by the version that I used does not support for window 32bit?

any helps would be appreciated.
thanks

Comment: did you try and run the Windows Media Encoder separately and see if it works?

Comment: I got the same problem. I can run the Windows Media Encoder separately, but cannot run my application with the same statement.

Answer (score 0):

Try targeting x86 instead of Any CPU in the properties of your .NET project. IIRC Windows Media Encoder is a native 32 bit component.